# Mock - Although setup .Returns(true) but always get false

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have code snippet as following. Although setup with retrurn true but value always return false.

Could someone advise how to retrieve value as true?

```
public interface IDatabaseService
  {
    bool ProcessSQL(INApplicationProcessDTO inApplicationProcessDTO, string connectionString, string storedProcedureName);
    bool CompleteRun(INApplicationProcessDTO inApplicationProcessDTO, string connectionString, string storedProcedureName);
  }
```

----CLASS----------

```
public static class INHelper
{
    public static bool CompleteRun(INApplicationProcessDTO inApplicationProcessDTO, string connectionString = null, IDatabaseService databaseService = null)
    {
      if (inApplicationProcessDTO == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
      if (inApplicationProcessDTO.Data == null)
      {
        return false;
      }
      const string storedProcedureName = "PSP_PWS_INApplication_Application_Process_CompleteRun";

      // Get Connection String to Parity4 Database from Parity4 WebService Web.config
      if (connectionString == null)
      {
        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"] != null)
        {
          connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }
      }
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
      {
        return false;
      }

      if (databaseService == null)
      {
        databaseService = new DatabaseService();
      }
      //Why always return false line below
      return databaseService.CompleteRun(inApplicationProcessDTO, connectionString, storedProcedureName);
    }
}
```

----TEST METHOD----

```
public void When_CompleteRun_ConnectionValid_Expect_True()
    {
      var iNApplicationProcessDTOTest = new INApplicationProcessDTO()
      {
        Data = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(),
        ErrorCount = 0,
        Errors = ""
      };

      Mock<IDatabaseService> iDatabaseService = null;
      iDatabaseService = new Mock<IDatabaseService>();
      iDatabaseService.Setup(t => t.CompleteRun(iNApplicationProcessDTOTest, "test", "test")).Returns(true);
      iDatabaseService.Setup(t => t.ProcessSQL(iNApplicationProcessDTOTest, "test", "test")).Returns(true);

      var iNApplicationProcessDTO = new INApplicationProcessDTO()
      {
        Data = new System.Xml.Linq.XDocument(),
        ErrorCount = 0,
        Errors = ""
      };
      var actual = INHelper.CompleteRun(iNApplicationProcessDTO, "a", iDatabaseService.Object);
      //actual always false although Returns(true) in Setup
      Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);
    }
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of tiny problems with your Test code.

First let me show how you should implement it and then let me give you some explanation:

```cs
[Fact]
public void GivenAFlawlessDatabaseService_WhenICallCompleteRun_ThenItCallsTheUnderlyingServicesCompleteRun()
{
    //Arrange
    const string connectionString = "a";
    var iDatabaseService = new Mock<IDatabaseService>();

    iDatabaseService
        .Setup(db => db.CompleteRun(It.IsAny<INApplicationProcessDTO>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(true);

    var iNApplicationProcessDTO = new INApplicationProcessDTO
    {
        Data = new XDocument(),
        ErrorCount = 0,
        Errors = ""
    };

    //Act
    var actual = INHelper.CompleteRun(iNApplicationProcessDTO, connectionString, iDatabaseService.Object);
    
    //Assert
    Assert.True(actual);
    iDatabaseService.Verify(db => db.CompleteRun(iNApplicationProcessDTO, connectionString, "PSP_PWS_INApplication_Application_Process_CompleteRun"), Times.Once);
    iDatabaseService.Verify(db => db.ProcessSQL(It.IsAny<INApplicationProcessDTO>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Never);
}
```

- First, I would suggest to use somewhat more meaningful names for your tests. Here I've used a Given When Then structure to describe under what circumstances (given) if a specific action is triggered (when) what would I expect (then)
- I also suggest to use the `Arrange`, `Act` and `Assert` comments to separate different phases of your test case visually
- The `Setup` method calls normally do not rely on concrete objects. The reason behind it is that classes are compared by reference. So, even if you have two seemingly identical instances (like: `iNApplicationProcessDTOTest` and `iNApplicationProcessDTO`) they are different. That's why the mock function is not being called.

  - Use `It.IsAny<T>()` calls in the `Setup` phase and use concrete values in the `Verify` phase.
- If one of the methods of the mocked object is not called by the SUT (system under test) then you don't need to `Setup` it.

  - But you can still verify that it has not been called (`Verify(..., Times.Never);`)

Comment: Thank you so much your answer. You helped me understand more about Mock and Unit test. I am new with Unit test. Your answer has resolved my issue.